# Checking for a condition of the same attribute twice?

Tags: relational-algebra

I have a question for you all, I can't find any answers on the internet I have been searching like mad.

Suppose that we have the following table to work with.
employee(station, name).
Now if I want to figure out the name of the employee/s that work in station A I can do it like this:

πname(σstation='A'(employee))

This should return the name/s of the employee/s that work in building A.

But I am a bit confused when it comes to checking if an employee works in 2 different stations. I have never seen this in relational algebra when one attribute is used twice for 2 conditions. So my question to you all is if this is a legit way of doing it?

πname(σstation='A'^station='B'(employee))

Is this okey? Will this return the names of the employee/s that work/s in building A and B? Am I allowed to do it like this or am I breaking some relation algebra rule?

Thanks a lot to anyone that can help me out with this doubt of mine.

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give a reference and/or definition for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. PS No attribute value of a row is ever both equal to 'A' & equal to 'B'. PS This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each row has only one station, the expression that you proposed will never return anything (no station is both equal to A and to B!).

So one way of solving your problem is to find all the employees with station = 'A' and intersect them with those with station = 'B' with the intersection operator:

```
πname(σstation='A'(employee)) ∩ πname(σstation='B'(employee))
```

In this way if an employee works both in station A and in station B it is returned.

Comment: Thank you very much good sir, this is exactly what I was looking for.